# Passing List of Object in WCF Using SOAP PHP

Tags: c#, php, wcf

How do you pass a list of object in a wcf webservice using soap php.

in my wcf webservice. i have this operation contract called.

```
//interface.cs
[OperationContract]
List<ResponseObj> OperationContractMethod( List<RequestObj> Request );

//RequestObj.cs
public class RequestObj {
 public string param1 {get;set;}
 public string param2 {get;set;}
...
}
```

inside my php client.

```
$this->soapClient = new SoapClient($soap_address);        

$params = array();

foreach( $array_obj as $obj){
 array_push($params, array('param1'=>$obj->param1, 'param2'=> $obj->param2));  
}

$this->soapClient->OperationContractMethod($params);
```

when i display the `$params` it would look like this

```
dd( $params );
array:13 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "param1" => "string"
    "param2" => "string"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▶]
  2 => array:2 [▶]
  3 => array:2 [▶]
...
]
```

The `Request` parameter counts `null` inside the `OperationContractMethod` method

PS: The OperationContractMethod works fine in my WCFClient btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically we should include the parameter names of the object;

correct way is to add the parameter name `$params["Request"]` (in this example its the `Request`) when adding an object into your array.

so it should be.

```
foreach( $array_obj as $obj){
 array_push($params["Request"], array('param1'=>$obj->param1, 'param2'=> $obj->param2));  
}
```

the list of obj should look like this in our var_dump.

```
 "Request" => array:13 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▶]
    1 => array:2 [▶]
    2 => array:2 [▶]
   ...
   ]
```

PS. anyone, feel free to add on what i miss